# Combining data from different locations to test difference in populations

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric, wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test

I have (irregularly spaced) times series concentration data for four locations and am trying to discern whether or not there has been a change in concentrations after a particular event. To avoid having to make assumptions about population distributions, I would like to use non-parametric techniques.

While boxplots of the data before and after the event seem to indicate that median concentrations may be lower after the event at each of the four locations, Mann-Whitney/Kruskal-Wallis tests are unable to reject the Null hypothesis (that the populations are the same), possibly due to the limited concentration data before and after the event (around 20 measurements each) and the high variability of the data.

As (based on the boxplots) it appears like concentrations may have declined after the event at all four locations, I am wondering if there is a technique whereby I can test if the observation that the concentrations appeared to decline at all four locations may be significant (despite the fact that tests on the individual locations were unable to reject the Null hypothesis).

Comment: Stop hunting for a low p-value!

Comment: It's not clear to me that Kruskal Wallis is suitable; ignoring the possibility of time dependence (aside the effect of the intervention), aren't there two factors here -- before/after and location?

Comment: I am not sure that I am hunting for a low p-value, but I am looking to try to determine whether there may have been an effect with a limited noisy environmental data set. It seems like there might be, but whether or not a regulator agrees, is another matter and it would be helpful to be able indicate that they may be statistically different rather than simply having to state that the power of the test isn't high enough.

Comment: @Glen_b Thanks for the response. Yes, there are two factors, before/after and location. Do have any suggestions as to what you think might be suitable? Within each of the locations, the use of KW is, I think applicable, but what I'd like to do is combine the results somehow (or use another test) to account for the second factor location (I don't simply want to group all of the data because the populations at the various locations may be different, but ideally, the effect I am looking for should result in a decrease in the mean/median concentration at each of those locations.)

Comment: While I was originally asking for a non-parametric solution, if that is not required, I believe that the blog post below answers the question I was looking for. [link](http://daniellakens.blogspot.com/2015/10/practicing-meta-analytic-thinking.html)